# Can junit tests be run in parallel?

Tags: java, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a few junit tests that take a long time to run.  Is it possible to assign a thread to each test to run them concurrently?  How would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can.

If you are using maven. You can take help of

**maven-surefire-plugin**

In Spring,

You can check this [Link](http://incodewetrustinc.blogspot.in/2009/07/run-your-junit-tests-in-parallel-with.html)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <parallel>classes</parallel>
            <threadCount>5</threadCount>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> Solution 2: Junit4 provides parallel feature using **ParallelComputer**